# Elasticsearch painless query with python and export to excel with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch

I'm really new to python and I use it to make some queries on my elastisearch cluster. Then I use pandas to export the results into excel. The query use a painless script for aggregration within a time range.

This is an extract of the python code with the elasticsearch query

```
   elastic_client = Elasticsearch('host:9200',
                    http_auth=('login', 'password'))
 
   response = elastic_client.search(
        index='test',
        body={
      "size": 0,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": "now-1d/d",
                  "lte": "now/d"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "analyze_wildcard": "true",
                "query": "requestTime:[60 TO *]"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
      .... (here starts the painless script)
```

I need a single excel file with 7 sheet (one for each day of the week).

I need the `response` for every day of the week. The best it would be to run the script once a week (on monday) and export the result on an excel file but I don't know how to loop the query to run it for yesterday, two days ago, three days ago, etc.

Otherwise I can run the script every day and put the `response` into excel. But I don't know how to put the pandas dataframe into excel writing and reading from the same file without delete the previous sheets because every time I try to export the data, python create a new file and delete the old one.

Can someone help me please?

Thank you

Comment: you can use `pd.ExcelWriter()` to set the mode to append and add new sheets to an existing Excel file. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html